# How do the various ways of setting GHC options in haskell-stack work together

Tags: haskell-stack, compiler-flags

While setting up a deploy pipeline for optimised builds of a server application, I ran into some trouble getting the GHC options right with [stack-1.6.5](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/tree/v1.6.5).

In particular, from the docs it doesn't get clear to me how the various ways to specify GHC options work together and when and how they are applied.

As far as I can tell, there are X ways of specifying GHC options:

- globally as `ghc-options:` in `~/.stack/config.yaml` and/or `/etc/stack/config.yaml`, per package or with `"$locals"`, `"$targets"` or `"$everything"`
- in the project `stack.yaml` file, per package or with `"$locals"`, `"$targets"` or `"$everything"`
- in the project `package.yaml`/`.cabal` file, globally or per target
- in a dependency `stack.yaml`/`package.yaml`/`.cabal` files
- on the stack command line via `--ghc-options`
- and there is the `apply-ghc-options:` setting `locals`/`targets`/`everything` in `stack.yaml` and `~/.stack/config.yaml` and/or `/etc/stack/config.yaml`

I'd like to know which options are applied in the different build phases snapshots/locals/targets in which order and in which cases they are additive or override options given elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

good question, this is not adequately documented.  These tend to be additive.  Most of the logic for this is here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/657937b0ac5dbef29114b43e9c69e2b57198af85/src/Stack/Build/Source.hs#L131 . Here's the order, where later items in the list come later in the options provided to ghc:

- Options specified in the package.yaml / cabal file.
- `$everything` in ghc-options in stack.yaml
- `$locals` in ghc-options in stack.yaml
- `$targets` in ghc-options in stack.yaml
- Special options like `-fhpc` (--coverage) / `fprof-auto -fprof-cafs` (--profile) / `-g` (--no-strip).
- Options specified via `--ghc-options` on the CLI

There is currently an issue where `$everything` / `$locals` / `$targets` ghc-options specified in `.stack/config.yaml` are not additive.  Instead they are currently shadowed by the project `stack.yaml`.  There is a PR fixing this, it will probably get merged at some point: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/pull/3781